# Improper integral convergence problem comparison

Tags: improper-integrals

Does the following improper integral converge ?

$$\int _1^{\infty}\:\cfrac{e^{1/x}-1}{x}dx$$

I have tried to compare it to some known improper integrals but with no luck.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that as $x\to \infty$, $e^{1/x}=1+\frac1x+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: $$\int _1^{\infty}\:\cfrac{1+1/x-1}{x}dx =\int _1^{\infty}\:\cfrac{1}{x^2}dx$$ that converges, is that correct?

Comment: @Richy65 Yes, it converges.  Well done!

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  ;-)